# Is it possible to do this query with a loop in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible  to do this query with a loop, or a list, to get the results for several indexes?  Thank you.

```
select ctx_report.create_index_script('LISTOFINDEXES') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a list of index names with a collection:

```
select ctx_report.create_index_script(column_value)
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('INDEX_1', 'INDEX_2'));
```

Or you could base it on the data dictionary:

```
select ctx_report.create_index_script(index_name)
from user_indexes
where ...
```

or perhaps more usefully:

```
select ctx_report.create_index_script(idx_name)
from ctx_user_indexes;
```